# How many algebraic closures can a field have?

Tags: set-theory, fields, axiom-of-choice

Assuming the axiom of choice given a field $F$, there is an algebraic extension $\overline F$ of $F$ which is algebraically closed. Moreover, if $K$ is a different algebraic extension of $F$ which is algebraically closed, then $K\cong\overline F$ via an isomorphism which fixes $F$. We can therefore say that $\overline F$ is *the* algebraic closure of $F$.

(In fact, much less than the axiom of choice is necessary.)

Without the axiom of choice, it is consistent that some fields do not have an algebraic closure. It is consistent that $\Bbb Q$ has two non-isomorphic algebraically closed algebraic extensions.

It therefore makes sense to ask: Suppose there are two non-isomorphic algebraically closed algebraic extensions. Is there a third? Are there infinitely many? Are there Dedekind-infinitely many?

> What is provable from $\sf ZF$ about the spectrum of algebraically closed algebraic extensions of an arbitrary field? What about the rational numbers?

Comment: Not fully sure about the tags, though.

Comment: Very cool question, could you provide a reference/proof hint for the comment about the consistency $\mathbb{Q}$ having more than one algebraic closure without choice?

Comment: Alec, it appears in Hodges' *Läuchli's algebraic closure of $Q$*. Math. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 79 (1976), no. 2, 289–297. [MR422022](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=422022).

Comment: Much appreciated Asaf; it seems I take choice for granted all too often, I thought these facts were more intrinsic to field theory.

Comment: Is this related? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114978/algebraic-closure-for-mathbbq-or-mathbbf-p-without-choice

Comment: @Matt: Not really. That tells us that for the rational numbers there is a canonical algebraically closed algebraic extension, so the spectrum is non-empty. But it's pretty far from anything I'm asking.

Comment: Oh my misunderstanding. As an outsider to this, I'm excited to see what comes out of this question. Cheers.

Comment: @Matt: Not much, I expect. But maybe with time someone will find this interesting enough to pursue from a research point of view.

Comment: It seems we can ask a similar question even with choice (but without global choice) about proper class sized fields like the field of fractions of the Grothendieck ring of the ordinals, since the poset/chains we want to Zorn are proper classes. It might be interesting to see how many algebraic closures a proper class sized field can have in the presence of choice without global choice.

Comment: Does the consistency of two closures follow because there are two sets for which no bijection exists and  each set is contained by one of the closures?  In which case, I suspect there are more  than two closures.  Gerhard "It's Not About The Algebra?" Paseman, 2019.03.19.

Comment: @Gerhard: In the case of the rationals, I guess? There is a canonically constructed closure which is countable. But it is consistent that there is an algebraically closed algebraic extension which is not countable. In fact, it does not have a real-closed subfield.

Comment: @AlecRhea The answer seems pretty likely to be "proper class many", right?

Comment: @WillSawin My intuition says yes, but I’m not sure — perhaps field properties like being formally real or having a particular valuation could have some impact on the answer.  Hopefully looking at the arguments in the paper Asaf linked above can sharpen it somewhat.

Comment: What happens to the model theoretic results about algebraically closed fields without choice?  Can you have uncountable nonisomorphic ACFs with the same characteristic and cardinality without choice?

Comment: @Noah: That's a good question. I don't know. It is true that the standard axiomatization of ACF is complete.

Comment: @Noah: Some months ago I was talking with another MO user about this question, and I realised that one of my recent papers implies that it is consistent that every field has a proper class of pairwise non-isomorphic algebraic closures, unless it is real-closed or algebraically closed. It's still not clear whether or not we can have some of them having the same cardinality. That's a great little idea.

Comment: @AsafKaragila hi, may I ask which paper of yours implies this result? I would like to read it

Comment: @Holo: The one I am putting in arxiv later today. Check Monday's Replacements.

Comment: @Holo: https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.09285

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks!